# Java retrieving of data in ms access "Column not found" error

Tags: java, ms-access

i'm trying to program an application that retrieves data from ms access in java. this is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class testdb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\smartphone.accdb";
        Statement statement;
        ResultSet rs;
        Connection con;
        String sql = "SELECT dev_name,points FROM list";

        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(path, "", "");

            System.out.println("Connected");

            statement = con.createStatement();
            statement.executeQuery(sql);
            rs = statement.getResultSet();
            System.out.println(rs.getString("SELECT dev_name FROM list"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

it compiles correctly and gives and output of:

```
Connected
Got an exception
Column not found
```

please help.

Comment: Try using just `rs.getString("dev_name")`. You only need to specify the column name you want to retrieve. You also need to do at least one `rs.next()` before you can retrieve data from the ResultSet.

Comment: thanks mate! but is it wrong to put the whole select statement? and also i didn't know about that next() function so thank you for that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
rs.getString("SELECT dev_name FROM list")
```

to

```
rs.getString("dev_name")
```

Also iterare the ResultSet using

```
while(rs.next())
```

To iterate the ResultSet you use its next() method. The next() method returns true if the ResultSet has a next record, and moves the ResultSet to point to the next record.If there were no more records, next() returns false.

Comment: wow thanks man, it worked! i already tried the 

    rs.getString("dev_name") 

before but it still gives me the error. i don't know what is wrong but this help me. thanks!